# How to avoid 'database disk image malformed' error while loading large json file in python / pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to read a table from sqlite database (of size 4 gb). Each cell of the table is a json (few cells have large json format files in it).

The query works fine when I execute it within db browser but in Python it gives an error : 'Database disk image is malformed'

I have tried with different tables and the problem persists. The number of rows to fetch with the query, is about 5000 . However, each cell in itself might have a long json structured string (of about 10000 lines).

I have already tried working with replicas of database and with other databases. I tried following as well, in the db 
Pragma integrity check;
Pragma temp_store = 2;  // to force data into RAM

The problem seems to be linked with Pandas / Python than the actual DB:

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
            sql = """ 
                    select a.Topic, a.Timestamp, a.SessionId, a.ContextMask, b.BuildUUID, a.BuildId, a.LayerId,
                    a.Payload
                    from MessageTable a
                    inner JOIN
                    BuildTable b
                    on a.BuildId = b.BuildId
                    where a.Topic = ('Engine/Sensors/SensorData')
                    and b.BuildUUID = :job
                    """
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql, {"job" : '06c95a97-40c7-49b7-ad1b-0d439d412464'})
            sensordf = pd.DataFrame(data = cur.fetchall(), columns = ['Topic', 'Timestamp_epoch', 'SessionId', 'ContextMask'
                                    'BuildUUID', 'BuildId', 'LayerId', 'Payload'])
```

I expect the output to be in pandas dataframe with the last column containing json values in each cell. I can further write some script to parse from json to extract more data.